# Pass array of arrays to function as if it was individual arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I have a variable that contains an array. That array contains X number of nearly identical arrays that I want to merge together.

But since they're already in an array variable, I can't pass it to `array_merge()` like this:

```
array_merge( $AoA );
```

What I'd like to do is this, but I can't because I don't know how many items are in the array:

```
array_merge(
  $AoA[0],
  $AoA[1],
  $AoA[2],
  // etc ...
);
```

Is there a short hand I can use to accomplish this without having to run them through a foreach loop? Or is it just late and I'm missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`call_user_func_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php), passing in `array_merge` as a string and your array of arrays, which the function then treats as an array of arguments to the function:

```
call_user_func_array('array_merge', $AoA);
```